# Logical fallacy: no one would be so dumb to

Tags: fallacies

Fact: the car peeling away from the robbed bank has Alice's license plate

Conclusion 1: suggests Alice might be involved in the bank robbery.

Conclusion 2: if Alice was involved in the robbery, she wouldn't be so stupid to use her own car. So this evidence actually suggests she was not involved in the robbery.

It strikes me that Conclusion 2 is some kind of fallacy, or maybe both put together are a fallacy, because the Fact cannot suggest both involvement and no involvement.

Help on the name of this fallacy?

(Maybe it is related to the economist who does not pick up the dollar bill because if it was real, someone would have already picked it up.)

Comment: Conclusions 1 and 2 use different implicit premises, namely, assumptions about Alice's level of intelligence, and there is nothing surprising that the same fact combined with them leads to different conclusions. However, "people are not that dumb" argument is, in general, fallacious, because first, some people are that dumb, and second, even generally smart people act that dumb at times. Some call excessive rationalism in judging human decisions [rational fallacy](https://www.informationphilosopher.com/freedom/rational_fallacy.html).

Comment: This seems similar to the Latin 'cut bono?'. 'Who profits (from this)' was used to convince a jury that someone should be suspected of some act, though it was accepted by itself as evidence. It is more a rule of thumb, and it can defeat itself by self-reference. Example: father is killed. The first son should inherit, unless he murdered his father, in which case the second son inherits...

Comment: Conclude informally while sitting on your couch watching the news on tv? Or conclude legally as a member of the jury? Seeing someone drive away from a crime is not evidence that they committed the crime. It doesn't matter what the public thinks. It matters what the law says.

Answer (score 2):

If there are two facts: "Alice's car was used in the bank robbery" and "Alice would not be so stupid", then 1 and 2 don't contradict one another at all. The evidence suggests (if we grant both premises) that Alice might be involved in the bank robbery, but she probably wasn't. Very well, Alice is a suspect but we shall focus the investigation elsewhere.

If there is really only the one fact, and it's not "Alice would not be so stupid", then 2 has a spurious conclusion by valid induction from a false premise.

Answer (score 0):

> Logical fallacy: no one would be so dumb to

Sounds like an argument from incredulity.

https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Argument-from-Incredulity